# Run groovy shell interactively on java application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

I have a Java application with its respective main function

I want to debug the application using Groovy, by running a Groovy shell which should share living objects with the Java application.

Think on a game where I'd like to change the State from a Groovy console.

My objective is to test the impact of misbehavior on a network, so I want to avoid changing the source code as much as possible, while I welcome any hackish way of doing it.

My original idea was to run a "Groovy Shell" right before the app runs and somehow connect to it later, and later retrieve the app status through a singular static variable which would hold an App object.

Something like this

Java:

```
public static App app;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (flags()) {
        new GroovyShell(config).run();
    }
    app = new App(config);
    app.run();
}
```

and in a Groovy file do something like
Groovy:

```
def app = Main.app
app.hackishMethod()
```

and run it after the app is initalized, whenever I want, as many times I want. Or a Groovy shell

If possible, I'd like to do it from Intellij

Comment: All is possible, but not clear what exactly you are not able to do.

Comment: I think pointers can be found in Grails2 - that did the same with the console-command.  It started the whole application up and put the developer into the console with grails/spring context available.